# moment().format(...).format is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs

I am going off of the example here:
https://devhints.io/moment

I am using:

```
 import moment from moment;

 const m = moment(v.created)
            .format()
             .format('dddd')
             .format('MMM Do YY') // → "Sep 2nd 07"
              .fromNow() // → "31 minutes ago"
              .calendar() // → "Last Friday at 9:32PM"
```

where v.created is a string that looks like `2020-01-02T21:49:53.3Z`

I am on version 2.22 of the momentjs library. Anyone know why I am getting this error:

> moment().format(...).format is not a function

Comment: `format()` returns a string, not a `moment` object, you can't chain it.

Comment: What are you expecting `.format('dddd').format('MMM Do YY')` to return?

Comment: The example you gave from https://devhints.io/moment  is just showing different ways to use `.format()`, `.fromNow()`, and `.calendar()` on the moment object. Not that you can chain them together

Comment: yeah that example from the devhints website is really wrong/confusing sad